# Delete all records starting with the same word in a particular column

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to delete all records starting with Backup from the "name" column of the MySQL database.

In the name column, the backup jobs look like this:

```
Backup-2854849
Backup-2852797
Backup-2852797
Backup-2326529
```

How do I write a query to delete all records that start with Backup in the "name" field.

I am able to delete a single record with the following query:

```
mysql>delete from JobInstance WHERE  name  LIKE  ‘Backup Configuration Files-860410’;
```

where JobInstance is the table name and name is the column name.

How do I delete them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
delete from JobInstance WHERE name LIKE ‘Backup℅’;
```

℅ operator matches anything that follows Backup

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard

```
delete from JobInstance WHERE name LIKE 'Backup%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

delete from JobInstance WHERE  name  LIKE  'Backup%';